# Resume NSTimer when view loads back

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

So I have a view that has a timer on it. So when you press "start" the NSTimer starts updating the UILabel with the time elapsed. Now when you press back to previous view, I store the current duration of the timer and when I load this view back I want to start the NSTimer again but this time I want to display the time that has passed.

So for example,

Start timer: 0:0:0
Pressed back at: 0:0:10 
When I come back to the view after 30 seconds, right now NSTimer starts back from: 0:0:10 when it should be at 0:0:40

This is how I am calculating the resume time:

```
NSDate *resumeDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

Any idea on how to get the correct timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

An `NSTimer` cannot be "started again". Once you start the timer all you can do is let it run or stop it.

You have to create a new `NSTimer` object with the new timestamp.

As for how to add to a timestamp, the `NSTimeInterval` data type is an alias for a standard C `double` value. So you can just do this:

```
interval += 4.2 // add 4.2 seconds to the interval
```

Answer (score -2):

You can not pause a timer but to stop it. So if you want to "Resume NSTimer", you can only create a new timer the same as your previous timer and let it run.